# Can I change Preferences file name?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my application, I am attempting to use sharedPreferences to save some basic settings as well as a Preference Screen. The name for my sharedPreferences is appPrefs and thus my file name is .../appPrefs.xml
However, my app screen saves it's preferences in the defaultSharedPreference file which is com.COMPANY.PACKAGENAME_preferences.xml

What I would like to do is have my preference screen read/write its preferences to the appPrefs file. I have looked in the API and can't find anything. Am I stuck managing two sharedPreference files?

Answer (score 42):

Just to answer the question about how to use different shared settings name with the new **PreferenceFragment API**, you need to add the following code when overriding *onCreate*:

```
public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PreferenceManager manager = getPreferenceManager();
        manager.setSharedPreferencesName("YOUR_SETTINGS_NAME");

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, I had to define the settings file name in the `onCreatePreferences`method (instead of in onCreate) for it to work.

Comment: Yeah, if you have the same problem like @TouchBoarder just add this lines to the `onCreatePreferences` method: `PreferenceManager manager = getPreferenceManager();
            manager.setSharedPreferencesName("WHATEVER");`

Answer (score 9):

Did you try:

```
PreferenceManager.setSharedPreferencesName
```

Comment: I have tried, but I keep getting an error saying that the function does not exist.
Also, the addPreferencesFromResource does not have a variable to pass a PreferenceManager so I don't know how I would bind the two together even if I could get the function to work correctly.

Comment: Which error ? Which "function" ? Add code and stack trace please.

Comment: After looking through some examples, I found that this function can be called by calling it from getPreferenceManager() so I am able to do that. I will see if it uses this preference name instead of the default.